# WP_CLI - how to get / set path

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I've installed WP-CLI but it says "This does not seem to be a wordpress installation".
The `wp` keyword works.

So I set path: `wp --path '/home/somefolder/okay/websitefolder'`

But then it says "No Wordpress installation found". It also says `'/home/somefolder/okay/websitefolder' is not a registered wp command`.

I also tried setting the path without citation.

I read that there should be a `version.php` file inside `wp-includes`, and there is such a file.

I wanted to check what path is currently set, but didn't find any info on how to **get** global parameter values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's no one-time set method. It's just a global parameter you pass to any WP-CLI command to specify the location of a WordPress to work on. See the handbook on [Config](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/).

> WP-CLI has a series of global parameters (e.g. `--path=<path>` and
>   `--user=<user>`) which work with all commands. They are called global
>   parameters because they affect how WP-CLI interacts with WordPress,
>   and have the same behavior across all commands.

For example:

```
$ wp plugin status --path=/home/somefolder/okay/websitefolder
```

The alternative is:

```
$ cd /home/somefolder/okay/websitefolder
$ wp plugin status
```

Comment: I thought the 'path' parameter would be associated with the "wp" command throughout the SSH session. Now when I went into the folder and try a command "wp plugin activate hello", now it works suddenly. I must have done some strange mistake(!) So I can use the wp command as long as I'm inside the project folder. I think I also forgot to add equal sign '=' after 'path'. Your first line with 'path' works for me when I try it. I guess it is solved then,thanks!